# Can not push elements to array inside while read loop

Tags: bash, shell

I found strange problem in bash: pushing to array is not working when I use `while read` loop

Here is an example:

```
#!/bin/bash
LINES=$(cat <<EOF
line1
line2
line3
EOF
)
declare -a x
x+=("x0")
echo "$LINES" | while read line ; do
  echo "debug: $line"
  x+=("$line")
done
echo "${x[@]}"
echo "DONE"
```

`echo "${x[@]}"` shows only `x0` but must be `x0 line1 line2 line3`

If I use `while` without `read` everything is ok:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a x
COUNTER=0
while [  $COUNTER -lt 10 ]; do
  let COUNTER=COUNTER+1
  x+=("$COUNTER")
done
echo "${x[@]}" # 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Please help me to figure out what is the problem

My bash version is `5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024

Comment: I probably gave a wrong link when closing the question, sorry. Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/53504334/1030675 instead.

Comment: @choroba, thanks so much, you helped me a lot! Will post an answer with rewritten code